# can't minimize Firefox in 13.04 (LiveDVD)

Tags: firefox, freeze, 13.04, minimize

Largely enjoyed my experience with 64-bit 13.04 from the LiveDVD - seems quite faster than 12.04's Unity!  However, Firefox froze when I minimized it, then kind of tried to 'come back' after a few seconds of me waiting for it, then froze again.

Is this at all related to the fact that I was using the LiveCD/DVD/whatever it's called now? And if I can reproduce it, what do I need to relay to the correct individuals?

EDIT - I see now this is a recognized issue of Ubuntu 13.04 - #1163503 on Launchpad. Since I prefer Chromium on Ubuntu I have my workaround, and I see that since it is a bug I will not need to keep this post open.  Thanks for being helpful, everyone.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: So I take it to mean that this is NOT an anticipated side-effect of booting from the LiveCD/DVD.  All right then, sorry for being off-topic, just didn't know what to expect.  As an aside, this is not a problem in Chromium or any other app/window I've tried out so far, so the workaround is self-evident, but I will followup on the bug report.  I'm sure someone somewhere actually uses Firefox.. probably.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uße this as a guide to report a bug if thats the case

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

But its probably the CD, try burning another copy